# Polynomial growth implies locally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, nonlinear-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ satisfy $\|f(x)\|\le c\|x\|^n$ for some (re-edit:) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with some constant $c>0$. Is $f$ locally Lipschitz?

I see that it is around $x=0$: $\|f(x)-f(0)\|\le \frac{c\|x\|^n+c0}{\|x\|}\|x\|=c\|x\|^{n-1}\|x\|\le \delta \|x\|$ for a suitable $\delta$.

Apparently, a polarization argument is a way to go but I do not know how to apply it for $\|f(x)-f(x')\|$.

Comment: What definition of "locally Lipschitz" are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample is 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \|x\|^{n-1}x, \|x\|\in\mathbb Q\\
-\|x\|^{n-1}x, \|x\|\not\in\mathbb Q
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: Is it obvious that this is a counter example ?

Comment: @Surb: Yes, since it is discontinuous.

Comment: @Surb: I have modified my counterexample for it to work for arbitrary $m$.

Comment: I have already upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @Surb: I understand. Thank you. :-) I just want to address your previous concern for $m>1$.

Answer (score 3):

I think the function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ define by $f(x)=x \sin (1/x)$ is a counter example to your problem.

Comment: This is not a counterexample, because local Lipschitz allows constants be dependent on $x$.

Comment: There is nothing to reconcile. The definition of local Lipschitz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions is satisfied for this example in the answer.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought. Great, thanks. The example "Differentiable functions that are not (locally) Lipschitz continuous" in the wikipedia page is very confusing.

Comment: @Hans The definition of "locally Lipschitz" you cite requires that for each $x,$ there exists a full neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in which $f$ is Lipschitz. There is no such neighborhood of $0$ for the example of AlexL, so it is a valid counterexample.

Comment: @Surb No, the example offered by AlexL is not locally Lipschitz. Perhaps you are thinking of "pointwise Lipschitz"?

Comment: The definition of locally Lipschitz is "for all neighbourhood $U_x$, for all $y$, $z$ in $U_x$, etc.". None of $y$ and $z$ have to be $x$. So the counterexample is obviously valid.

Comment: @Surb What definition of "locally Lipschitz" are you using?

Comment: @zhw. the wrong one :|

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: You are right, that Lipschitz should be for all $y,z in U_x$. I retract my objection. zhw is right, too.

Comment: +1. Good counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

The Weierstrass function $W(x)$ presented in baby Rudin  is a continuous bounded function on $\mathbb R$ such that

$$\limsup_{h\to 0}\left |\frac{W(x+h)-W(x)}{h}\right| =\infty$$

for every $x\in \mathbb R.$ The function $f(x) = xW(x)$ satisfies $|f(x)|\le c|x|$ on $\mathbb R.$ It also satisfies

$$\limsup_{h\to 0}\left |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| =\infty$$

for all $x\ne 0.$ Exercise: Prove this. It follows that $f$ fails to be Lipschitz in every nonempty open interval, including the ones containing $0.$ This function is therefore "nowhere locally Lipschitz".

Answer (score 1):

A continuous nowhere differentiable function such as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sin(2^n x)\over n^2}$$
is bounded but it most certainly is not locally lipschitz.

Comment: really? continuous implies uniform continuity on any compact isn't it?

Comment: This is uniformly continuous, but it is not locally lipschitz. That is a far stronger condition than continuity.

Comment: right makes sense, I mixed up two definitions$

Comment: Seems to be a legitimate example. But can you actually prove it is not locally Lipschitz or provide a reference to the proof of this claim?